# Trouble to install a userform as an add-in in Excel and Word

Tags: vba, excel, add-in, userform, office-addins

I have created a vba userform that will appear when I want to print something from exel or word. But I have trouble to install it as add-in (so it will apply to all office documents I try to print).

I found a similar question and used the code for installation mentioned there but it give me an error.

Here is the link: [How to create a macro that will open a userform from an Add-in without opening the workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509738/how-to-create-a-macro-that-will-open-a-userform-from-an-add-in-without-opening-t)

Here is the error:

> An unexpected error has occured, please contact CSC DM
>
> Design with the bellow error details.
>
> Module = UserfulGeneric Code
>
> Procedure = CreateMMMacroMenu
>
> Line = 0
>
> Error Code = 91
>
> Error Text = Object veriable or With block variable not set

Is there anything I can do to resolve that? I'm new to vba and any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, you need the Excel AddIn workbook has the property `IsAddIn` set to `True` and saved as a **.xlam** file. The menu **Actions** should be a valid Sub within the AddIn file. If you copy everything in your supplied link, please comment out the **On Error Resume Next**, then try step through it since the **Erl** for `Line = 0` is not defined/changed so it does not help where the actual error is at.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I saved my workbook as an add-in file, so now it is an .xlam file with property IsAddiIn set to True. I loaded it to my excel as an add-in but it is not working. I think there is a problem with how it is activated or simply with my code. I have there Private Sub ThisDocument_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean) in ThisWorkbook mode and use Userform1.Show to open my user form. My code worked fine in the workbook where I created it but I have no idea how to make it work as an add-in.

Comment: You should have a read on [Application Events In An Existing Object Module](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be pretty simple for Excel:

To demonstrate, a file <kbd>TestAddIn.xlam</kbd> is created with **ThisWorkbook.IsAddin = True**, a Userform and codes in `ThisWorkbook` module.

[image: ProjectWindow]

---

Codes in **ThisWorkbook** Module:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforePrint(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Debug.Print Now & " " & "App_WorkbookBeforePrint: " & Wb.FullName
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
    'Debug.Print Now & " " & "Loading " & ThisWorkbook.FullName
End Sub
```

---

**UserForm1**:

[image: UserForm1]
**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
End Sub
```

---

Now make sure you add this AddIn normally via Excel UI, or use VBA to install into Excel. But you need to restart Excel afterwards.

When printing a new workbook: the userform shows up before it actually prints.
[image: userform demo]

Comment: I copy/pasted everything and when I try to print it says "Type Mismatch " and wants to debug **UserForm1.Show** in `Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforePrint(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Debug.Print Now & " " & "App_WorkbookBeforePrint: " & Wb.FullName
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub`

Comment: Can you check that the UserForm1 can be loaded? Within the codes for the UserForm1, press F5.

Comment: Oh, Thanks =) I had to add 1 to UserForm in `UserForm_Initialize()` =) Now it works perfect. Also a quick question, how I should edit the code you gave me to call the same UserForm but in Word?

Comment: Another thing, When I created my UserForm1 in excel I had to use cells A1 & A2 to store some info. In A1 UserName and in A2 the Date. After I converted it to add-in it seems like UserForm stopped getting this info from Sheet1 and does not output it into the LOGfile.

Comment: Here is the code for that : `Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    
    Me.DocumentName.Text = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    DocumentName.Visible = False
    
    TextBoxDate.Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "A").Value
    TextBoxDate.Value = CDate(TextBoxDate.Value)
     
UserName.Visible = False
Userform1.UserName.Text = CStr(Range("A1").Value)

 If UserName = "" Then
    UserRegister.Show
    End If
    
End Sub`

Comment: And the code for UserRegister form is `Private Sub UserName_Change()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = UserName.Text

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButtonGO_Click()

ThisWorkbook.Save
Unload Me

End Sub
`

Comment: For the AddIn Sheet1, you should reference it by `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(...)`.